# Calling generic method recursively with type change in c#

Tags: c#, generics, reflections

I using the following library to do the Bulk insert. [enter link description here](https://github.com/MikaelEliasson/EntityFramework.Utilities) i am trying to bulk insert a huge amount of data with its related items the solution is working fine with the first level but not inserting the children.

So, I have the following generic class

```
 public class EFBatchOperation<TContext, T> : IEFBatchOperationBase<TContext, T>, IEFBatchOperationFiltered<TContext, T>
    where T : class
    where TContext : DbContext{
      private ObjectContext context;
    private DbContext dbContext;
    private IDbSet<T> set;
    private Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate;

    public EFBatchOperation(TContext context, IDbSet<T> set)
    {
        this.dbContext = context;
        this.context = (context as IObjectContextAdapter).ObjectContext;
        this.set = set;
    }

    public static IEFBatchOperationBase<TContext, T> For<TContext, T>(TContext context, IDbSet<T> set)
        where TContext : DbContext
        where T : class
    {
        return new EFBatchOperation<TContext, T>(context, set);
    }
    public BatchOperationResult InsertAll<TEntity>(IEnumerable<TEntity> items, DbConnection connection = null, int? batchSize = null) where TEntity : class, T
    {
       // the problem is here I want to call the current function 'InsertAll' but after changing the type of the function. passing a different type to the function. I tried the following but its not working       var connectionToUse = connection ?? con.StoreConnection;
        var currentType = typeof(TEntity);
        var provider = Configuration.Providers.FirstOrDefault(p => p.CanHandle(connectionToUse));
        if (provider != null && provider.CanInsert)
        {
            var mapping = EntityFramework.Utilities.EfMappingFactory.GetMappingsForContext(this.dbContext);
         // use of T to get Type Mapping
            var typeMapping = mapping.TypeMappings[typeof(T)];


            var tableMapping = typeMapping.TableMappings.First();

            var properties = tableMapping.PropertyMappings
                .Where(p => currentType.IsSubclassOf(p.ForEntityType) || p.ForEntityType == currentType)
                .Select(p => new ColumnMapping { NameInDatabase = p.ColumnName, NameOnObject = p.PropertyName }).ToList();
            if (tableMapping.TPHConfiguration != null)
            {
                properties.Add(new ColumnMapping
                {
                    NameInDatabase = tableMapping.TPHConfiguration.ColumnName,
                    StaticValue = tableMapping.TPHConfiguration.Mappings[typeof(TEntity)]
                });
            }

            provider.InsertItems(items, tableMapping.Schema, tableMapping.TableName, properties, connectionToUse, batchSize);

         var objectContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter)this.dbContext).ObjectContext;
            var os = objectContext.CreateObjectSet<TEntity>();
            var foreignKeyProperties = os.EntitySet.ElementType.NavigationProperties.Where(x => x.ToEndMember.RelationshipMultiplicity == RelationshipMultiplicity.Many);
            Type entityType = typeof(TEntity);
            foreach (var foreignKeyProperty in foreignKeyProperties)
            {
                var childProperty = foreignKeyProperty.ToEndMember.GetEntityType();

                foreach (var item in items)
                {
                    var childValue = entityType.GetProperty(foreignKeyProperty.Name).GetValue(item);
                    Type childValueType = childProperty.GetType();

                    
                    //MethodInfo method = typeof(EFBatchOperation).GetMethod("InsertAll");
                    MethodInfo method = typeof(EFBatchOperation<TContext, T>).GetMethod("InsertAll");
                    var newMethod = method.MakeGenericMethod(new[] { childValueType.DeclaringType });
                    newMethod.Invoke(this, new object[] { childValue });
                    // InsertAll<>(childValue, connection, batchSize);
                }
            }
    }
   }
```

I am calling InsertAll function as follows:

```
 BatchOperationResult batchOperationResult = EFBatchOperation.For(context, dbSet).InsertAll(collectionOfEntitiesToInsert);
```

the problem is here I want to call the current function 'InsertAll' but after changing the type of the function. passing a different type to the function.

I have tried to call the function using reflection but its not working using the following code

```
   MethodInfo method = typeof(EFBatchOperation<TContext, T>).GetMethod("InsertAll");
   var newMethod = method.MakeGenericMethod(new[] { childValueType });
   newMethod.Invoke(this, new object[] { childValue });
```

and I got the following error

> GenericArguments [0], "System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.EntityType" for "EntityFramework.Utilities.BatchOperationResult InsertAll [TEntity] (System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1 [TEntity], System.Data.Common .DbConnection, System.Nullable`1 [System.Int32]) "exceeds the" TEntity "type constraint.

**Update:**

- the idea here is to insert child-related properties because the original code just inserted the main entity, not the child elements.
- Also Updated the code with more code to clarify what i am trying to do here

Comment: read the exception message. Your `childValueType` becomes `int?` and doesn't pass the generic constraint

Comment: `System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.EntityType`? So your `childValueType` is an `IEntityType`, not a `Type`? Then I think you need `childValueType.ClrType`.

Comment: @JeremyLakeman I think you are right i tried to convert the type from the value but i can't

Comment: What are you trying to write anyway? Can you replace the whole thing with `context.ChangeTracker.TrackGraph(...)`?

Comment: Mohamed, could you elaborate what are the <T> and <TEntity> types? Your `IDbSet<T> set` and `EFBatchOperation.For(context, dbSet)` strongly suggest that the T is not the entity base type, like Jeremy suspects, but a concrete entity type. If you call it like `EFBatchOperation.For(context, dbSet)` where for example, `var dbSet = context.Houses`, then you'll have T/TEntity type clash between 'parent' and 'child' classes (like in, `where` says `House`, and `T` is the child related `Tenant`).. and again, as Jeremy said, EntityFramework can track children for you, why are you doing it manually?

Comment: @quetzalcoatl <T> you are right this is a concrete entity type and you are totally correct in your illustration of the conflict between parent and child classes. and you are correct entity framework can detect and manage the children but here I am trying to SQLBulk copy to make bulk insert because Entity Framework is very slow in inserting bulk records so i tried this solution and it works fine in inserting the first line of the entity but the children couldn't be inserted.

Comment: @JeremyLakeman I am trying to write a bulk insert using SQL Bulk Copy because Entity Framework is very slow in inserting bulk entities.

Comment: Mohamed, ok, thanks for confirming this. However, I still fail to see why `InsertAll<TEntity>` needs a constraint of `where TEntity : class, T`. Can't you just drop it and leave simple `where TEntity : class`? Why do you need to relate the TEntity to T? What is it for? If no reason, just remove the `, T` from the constraint like I suggested in answer, and maybe it will "just work".

Comment: @MohamedSalah so this is a case of [the XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem): You have a problem X (how to *bulk* insert data) and assume Y is the solution - somehow creating a *batch* in EF Core. When that fails, you asked about the attempted solution, not the problem. First of all, EF Core already has batching. That's not the same as *bulk* INSERT though. For that you need SqlBulkCopy and either a DataTable or an IDataReader. You can convert any `IEnumerable<T>` to either

Comment: @MohamedSalah update the question explaining what the *actual* problem is.

Comment: @quetzalcoatl I updated the question with more code on why I used T. It's been used to get Type Mapping.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I updated the question with more code to show the rest of the code. I am not using EF Core to do so. and i am trying to bulk insert a huge amount of data with its related items the solution is working fine with the first level but not inserting the children. so this is why i am trying to do this.

Comment: @MohamedSalah you can't bulk insert into multiple tables - assuming by `bulk insert` you actually mean using the bulk insert mechanism. You have to load the parent table first, then any related tables. In fact, it's common to disable indexes and foreign key constraints during bulk operations to speed up the process. It's also common to bulk insert into staging tables and then either update the target table or even use partition switching to replace the actual with the staging data

Comment: @MohamedSalah besides, what you try to do right now is what EF Core already does. It already batches INSERTs. In fact, the actual statements it generates use table row constructors to insert as many rows as possible with a single SQL command , eg `INSERT INTO ... VALUES ( (value11,value12), (value21,value22)....)`.  This syntax is used for up to 2000 values. [The Case of Entity Framework Core’s Odd SQL](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2017/05/case-entity-framework-cores-odd-sql/) explains exactly what's going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that type `T` is some base class that all of your model entities extend? Including this `childValueType`?

From the error message, `System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.EntityType` does not qualify for the constraints on `TEntity`.

`EntityType` is the EF Core implementation of `IEntityType`. Though you have not included in your example where `childValueType` is defined, I believe you have assigned `childValueType = [IEntityType].GetType()`, where you intended `childValueType = [IEntityType].ClrType`.

Update, now that you have added more code. As I guessed, this; `childProperty.GetType();` should be `childProperty.ClrType`.

Comment: It looks like you are correct the type of childValueType is different than expected i will try to convert it to the desired type. I updated the question itself with more code for better understanding of the case

Comment: Jeremy, thanks for pointing out that `int?`!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, @JeremyLakeman for pointing out that I totally misread the exception message regarding `int?`.

---

Mohamed, your `InsertAll` method has `where TEntity : class, T` restriction. Even when calling it via reflection via MakeGenericMethod, you still cannot pass any arbitrary type - you have to pass a type that satisfies that restriction. This is what the error tells you: you have passed some type that does not satisfy either `class`, or `T` restriction.

That the `T` that comes from the class `EFBatchOperation`, and it apparently does not match the other entity type that `InsertAll` tries to process. For example, it starts with `EFBatchOperation<House>`, original method call is `InsertAll<House>` and it then tries to recurse into `InsertAll<Tenant>` - and fails, since Tenant probably does not comply with `class,House` restriction.

Is that relation between `<TEntity>` of InsertAll, and `<T>` of EFBatchOperation really needed? If not, just remove it and leave `where TEntity: class`. If it has to stay there for public calls, then maybe try writing a private version of InsertAll that can process any type and that doesn't require `<T>` and call it instead when recursing?

Answer (score 0):

From the comments it looks like the actual problem is how to *bulk* insert a lot of rows. That's *not* the same as batch updates (combining multiple statements in a single script).

EF Core [already batches updates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/performance/efficient-updating#batching) and even allows modifying the default batch size. Batching 42 `INSERTs` into a single script will still execute 42 fully logged INSERTs though. Inserting thousands of rows will still be slow.

[*Bulk* inserts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/bulk-import-and-export-of-data-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15) use the same [minimally logged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/prerequisites-for-minimal-logging-in-bulk-import?view=sql-server-ver15) mechanism as `bcp` or `BULK INSERT` to insert rows as fast as possible. Instead of logging every row change SQL Server will log the changes to the data pages. It's far faster than batching individual INSERT statements. Instead of caching records and changes in memory, the data is sent directly to the server in a stream.

There's no bulk update or delete mechanism, no matter what some libraries claim.

To perform bulk inserts you need the [SqlBulkCopy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0). That class accepts either a DataTable or an IDataReader. You can create an `IDataReader` wrapper over any `IEnumerable<T>` using [FastMember's ObjectReader](https://github.com/mgravell/fast-member#ever-needed-an-idatareader) :

```
var data = new List<Customer>();
....
using(var bcp = new SqlBulkCopy(connection)) 
using(var reader = ObjectReader.Create(data, "Id", "Name", "Description")) 
{ 
  bcp.DestinationTableName = "SomeTable"; 
  bcp.WriteToServer(reader); 
}
```

That's it.

`ObjectReader` will use the property names by default, or the list of names passed to `ObjectReader.Create`

By default, SqlBulkCopy doesn't use a transaction. [Transaction and Bulk Copy Operations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/transaction-and-bulk-copy-operations) explains how to use a transaction and how to configure the batch size to commit changes in batches if desired.